# Linux: How to display all sockets opened for a particular interface?

Tags: linux, socket, networking, netstat

How can I display all sockets opened for a particular interface?

Comment: What I was looking for was: ss -a0p

Comment: glad you found an answer. It might be helpful (for others) if you were to write it as an answer. (Yes, answering your own question)

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the -i parameter in netstat ?

Comment: that displays interfaces statistics, not open/listening sockets

Answer (score -2):

That would be `netstat -I interface`.

Comment: that displays interfaces statistics, not open/listening sockets